# Como exibir o trecho do script onde a exceção foi lançada em PHP

Tags: php, exceção

O PHP, quando uma exceção é lançada, é informado o arquivo e a linha onde a exceção foi lançada.

Exemplo:

```
try {

   throw new Exception('Só para mostrar a linha');

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getLine(); // 38
    echo $e->getFile(); // 'projeto/index.php'
}
```

Com base nessas informações, eu gostaria de ler as linhas dos arquivo onde a exceção foi lançada.Quero abrir o arquivo e ler 5 linhas antes e 5 linhas depois da linha 38 indicada acima.

Como eu poderia fazer isso em PHP?

Comment: ainda existem `$e->getMessage();` , `$e->getTraceAsString();`, `$e->getCode()`, `$e->getPrevious ()` e `$e->getTrace()` o ideal é você salvar um log, e depois abri-lo.

Comment: Não, mas eu quero fazer como está na pergunta mesmo. Eu quero exibir o trecho do script onde ocorreu o erro, igual a biblioteca Whoops faz.

Comment: usando `file_get_contents()` não resolve? ou `set_error_handler()`

Comment: [Tipo isso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php)

Comment: `file_get_contents` vai pegar tudo. Na verdade eu tenho uma solução, mas gostaria de aprender de um jeito melhor :D. Mas é isso, o set_error_handler é o caminho

Comment: Veja se [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) tem o caminho esperado.

Comment: Seria mais ou menos o mesmo mecanismo que o whoops usa?

Comment: Sim @rray, isso mesmo

Comment: Vai mostrar isso na página?

Comment: Quero fazer um Exception Handler que vai exibir os erros. Eu tenho uma ideia de como fazer, mas quero aprender a fazer melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gostei da resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento, mas gostaria também de deixar uma solução.

No PHP, para fazer isso, poderíamos usar a combinação de `SplFileObject` com `LimitIterator`.

O `LimitIterator` itera sobre um `Iterator`, de uma posição inicial passada até outra.

O `SplFileObject` também é um `Iterator`. A cara iteração, ele lê uma linha (ou uma determinada quantidade de dados específica) de um arquivo.

O PHP também possui uma função específica para manipular as exceções. Ou seja, não é necessário ficar fazendo `try/catch` toda vez que quiser aplicar essa funcionalidade. Basta apenas usar a função set_exception_handler que fará o trabalho.

Vamos lá:

```
set_exception_handler(function ($e)
{
     $fileObject = new SplFileObject($e->getFile(), 'r');
     // Definimos que vamos ver o trecho 5 linhas antes da exceção lançada e 5 depois

     $lines = new LimitIterator($fileObject, $e->getLine() - 5, $e->getLine() + 5);

   // Para exibir as linhas basta um foreach
   foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
        echo $line;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Penso que você poderia fazer algo similar a isso, eu não testei, não sei se serve, mas tenta lá:

```
function myFetchContents($fileError, $errorMessage, $errorLine) { 
        $fError = fopen($fileError, 'r');
        if ($fError) {
           $contentError = fread($fError, $errorLine);
           $errors = array( 'errorMessage' => $errorMessage,
                            'contentError' => nl2br($contentError));
          return $errors;
        }
} 

try { 
   //faz algo
} catch (Exception $e) { 
  $error = myFetchContents($e->getFile(), $e->getMessage, $e->getLine());
  var_dump($error); 
}
```

Comment: `fread` vai ler um determinado tamanho no buffer (o segundo argumento), e não a linha específica. Creio que nesse caso é o `fseek` que faz esse trabalho.

Comment: Outra alternativa é você utilizar a função `var_dump(ini_get('display_errors'))`, [- leia mais aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-get.php) ou `var_dump(error_get_last());` [- leia mais aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-get-last.php)

Answer (score 1):

Também sempre tive essa necessidade, principalmente se preciso trabalhar com mais pessoas e os arquivos tem constantes mudanças, as vezes perdemos algum problema, ou até mesmo temos que ficar localizando um arquivo e localizando o problema, tendo essa necessidade eu acabei criando uma biblioteca apenas pra este tipo de situação.

Um que lê uma parte do arquivo definida por quem usa: https://github.com/inphinit/framework/blob/master/src/Experimental/File.php#L16

E outra pra fazer a contagem de linhas assim exibindo além da linha que ocorre o problema (pois como eu disse em outra pergunta, as vezes o problema pode ter ocorrido alguns linhas antes):

https://github.com/inphinit/framework/blob/master/src/Experimental/Debug.php#L172

Então poderia usar o código assim:

```
function obterTrecho($source, $line)
{
    if ($line <= 0 || is_file($source) === false) {
        return null;
    } elseif ($line >= 5) {
        $init = $line - 5;
        $end  = $line + 5;
        $breakpoint = 5;
    } else {
        $init = 0;
        $end  = 5;
        $breakpoint = $line;
    }
    return array(
        'breakpoint' => $breakpoint,
        'preview' => explode(EOL, trechoArquivo($source, $init, $end, true))
    );
}

function trechoArquivo($path, $init = 0, $end = 1024)
{
    if (false === is_file($path)) {
        return false;
    }

    $i = 1;
    $output = '';
    $handle = fopen($path, 'rb');

    while (false === feof($handle) && $i <= $end) {
        $data = fgets($handle);
        if ($i >= $init) {
            $output .= $data;
        }
        ++$i;
    }

    fclose($handle);
    return $output;
}
```

Note que usei `rb` ao invés de `r` pois pode ocorrer de as vezes (raramente) precisar ler algo "binário", o uso dele ficaria assim:

```
try {

   throw new Exception('Só para mostrar a linha');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump(obterTrecho($e->getFile(), $e->getLine()));
}
```

Ele irá retornar algo como:

```
    array(
        'breakpoint' => 5,
        'preview' => array(
            'foo();',
            'outrocodigo();',
            '',
            'try {',
            '',
            '   throw new Exception('Só para mostrar a linha');',
            '',
            '} catch (Exception $e) {',
            '     var_dump(obterTrecho($e->getFile(), $e->getLine()));',
            '}'
         )
    );
```

Note que `breakpoint` se refere ao item do array de index 5, mas não exatamente a linha, o qual você pode usar pra destacar a linha que o PHP acusa estar com o problema, então você pode tratar estes dados com algo como:

```
function ExibeErro($file, $line)
{
    $source = obterTrecho($file, $line);

    $data = $source['preview'];
    $breakpoint = $source['breakpoint'];

    $lines = count($data);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $lines; $i++) {
        if ($breakpoint === $i) {
            echo '<strong style="color: red;">', htmlspecialchars($data[$i], ENT_QUOTES), '</strong>', EOL;
        } else {
            echo htmlspecialchars($data[$i], ENT_QUOTES), EOL;
        }
    }
}

...

try {

   throw new Exception('Só para mostrar a linha');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    ExibeErro($e->getFile(), $e->getLine()));
}
```

O interessante dele é que você pode implementar com `set_error_handler` assim também:

```
function handlerError($type, $message, $file, $line, $details = null)
{
    static $preventDuplicate; //Previne duplicidade dos erros (também é possivel fazer isto pelo php.ini)

    $str  = '?' . $file . ':' . $line . '?';

    if ($preventDuplicate === null) {
        $preventDuplicate = '';
    }

    if (strpos($preventDuplicate, $str) === false) {
        $preventDuplicate .= $str;
        echo '<h1>Erro: '$message, '</h1>';
        ExibeErro($file, $line);
    }

    return false;
}

function shutodownEvent()
{
    //Pega erros de PARSE
    $e = error_get_last();
    if ($e !== null) {
        handlerError($e['type'], $e['message'], $e['file'], $e['line']);
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutodownEvent');
set_error_handler('handlerError', E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```